# How do I return an error message when the user inputs wrong info?

Tags: ruby, if-statement, while-loop

I have a program that displays a numbered list and asks the user to input either a number or name from the list, and loops a block until the user enters `"exit"`, after which it ends.

I want to add a line or two that puts an error message like, `"Sorry, I don't seem to understand your request"` if the user inputs something that is not on the list (name/number) and is not the word `"exit"`.

I can't seem to figure it out. Any advice? My current code is below.

```
def start
  display_books
  input = nil
  while input != "exit"
    puts ""
    puts "What book would you more information on, by name or number?"
    puts ""
    puts "Enter list to see the books again."
    puts "Enter exit to end the program."
    puts ""
    input = gets.strip
    if input == "list"
      display_books
    elsif input.to_i == 0
      if book = Book.find_by_name(input)
        book_info(book)
      end
    elsif input.to_i > 0
      if book = Book.find(input.to_i)
        book_info(book)
      end
    end
  end
  puts "Goodbye!!!"
end
```

Comment: Can you show how the `display_books` shows?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems that you should add an `elsif` statement in this `if`:

```
if book = Book.find_by_name(input)
  book_info(book)
elsif input != 'exit'
  puts "Sorry, I don't seem to understand your request"
end
```

Answer (score 0):

A good template for an interpreter is to build around Ruby's very capable `case` statement:

```
loop do
  case (gets.chomp.downcase)
  when 'list'
    display_books
  when /\Afind\s+(\d+)/
    if book = Book.find($1.to_i)
      book_info(book)
    end
  when /\Afind\s+(.*)/
    if book = Book.find_by_name($1)
      book_info(book)
    end
  when 'exit'
    break
  else
    puts "Not sure what you're saying."
  end
end
```

Although this involves regular expressions, which can be a bit scary, it does give you a lot of flexibility. `\A` represents "beginning of string" as an anchor, and `\s+` means "one or more spaces". This means you can type in `find   99` and it will still work.

You can create a whole command-line interface with it if you take the time to specify the commands clearly. Things like `show book 17` and `delete book 17` are all possible with a bit of tinkering.